# Choose Gvim font that maps pixel-to-pixel with display?

Tags: fonts, xorg, cygwin-x

I was advised [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23081/7041) to post this question at Superuser, as it deals with both Windows and X11 (via Cygwin).

I recently bought a Windows 10 laptop, TravelMate P2410-G2-M.  The resolution is set to the native physical resolution of the display.

However, my Gvim text displays with some pixel columns/rows smeared over multiple display pixel column/rows:

[image]

**How can I identify fonts whose pixels map one-to-one with the pixels on the display?**

To clarify, I'm not asking about how to subjectively ascertain whether a font maps pixel-to-pixel with the display, i.e., through trial, error, and empirical observation, e.g., using `xfontsel` or Gvim's font picker (invoked with `set guifont=*`).  Rather, I'm hoping I can rely on something like a font family name or a one of the many font parameters such as those used by `xfontsel`.

**Contextual details**

The above is a general question, but the specific system I'm using is configured as follows:

- Using Windows 10 and 64-bit Cygwin's X-windows, downloaded and installed circa start of 2020
- The above screen shot of bleeding pixels was using the Gvim option guifont=Lucida\ Console\ Regular\ 9

**Possible hurdles**

- My Gvim installation seems to have access to different fonts than X11 in general.  I documented [what I found](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22650/7041) to make me suspect this.
- I am not sure whether running X11 on Windows introduces complications, e.g., a logical pixel grid that is mismatched with the physical grid, leading to antialiasing that would otherwise not be needed (totally wild speculation based on very little insight into how X11 works and how it is hosted on Windows).

Thanks.